# Plotly choropleth shows color for US and not other countries

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I've a pandas dataframe as  following :
[image: dataframe]

column `employee_residence` contains an ISO 3166 country code for each unique country .

I want to plot a [Choropleth map](https://plotly.com/python/choropleth-maps/) for the above dataframe which highlights the `mean_salary` as per the country on the map.

So I did the following :

```py
fig = px.choropleth(
    data_frame=salary_location_df,
    locations="employee_residence",
    locationmode="country names",
    color="mean_salary",
    hover_data=["mean_salary", "count_jobs"],
    title="country wise salaries",
)
fig.show()
```

but in the output I am only able to see US residence colored and not others
[image: plotly chorolepth output]

So I thought there might be something wrong with the country codes due to which only US is showing up thus I tried validating those country codes using ISO standard library located here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/iso3166/

[image: validating country codes]

but seems like all the country codes are valid

So what can be done in order to resolve this problem ?
Thank you

Comment: If you have an ISO3166-2 code, I think you can get the ISO3166-3 code using that code as a key, join it to the already existing data frame and specify the location as iso-alpha, and it will be color coded. If the location mode is set to country name, then location is set to country and it will be color coded. `px.choropleth(df, locations="iso_alpha", ...)` or `px.choropleth(df, locations="country",locationmode='country names',...)` See this:[Using Built-in Country and State Geometries](https://plotly.com/python/choropleth-maps/#using-builtin-country-and-state-geometries)

Comment: Tried both, not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update:**
Now that the data has been published, I used that data to recreate the graph. Since the original data is the ISO3166-2 format country abbreviation, install the library to get the ISO-3166-3 format country abbreviation. Add it to the original data frame and draw a graph.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px 

df = pd.read_csv("/content/ds_salaries.csv", index_col=0)

salary_location_df = df.groupby("employee_residence").agg(
    mean_salary=('salary_in_usd', 'mean'), count_jobs=('employee_residence', 'count')
).reset_index()

from iso3166 import countries

country_names =[]
for country in salary_location_df['employee_residence']:
    #print(country)
    c_name = countries.get(country)
    country_names.append(c_name[2])

salary_location_df['iso_alpha'] = country_names

fig = px.choropleth(salary_location_df, locations="iso_alpha",
                    color="mean_salary", 
                    hover_data=["mean_salary", "count_jobs"],
                    title="country wise salaries",
                    color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Plasma)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I tried similar to what you had suggested but its not working :( 
here's my kaggle notebook : https://www.kaggle.com/code/pathikghugare/data-science-job-eda